# SQL Group by for class column

Tags: sql, group-by

I have two products Green-M and Green-L both share the same productcode 'Clothes' but belong to different classes say Cap and Hat. (They were supposed to be of the same class)

Below are my tables

```
tbl_Product 

ProductName ProductId classic
Green-M      1        2
Green-L      1        3


tbl_size

sizeid   sizename
M           Medium
L           Large

tbl_Class
classid   classname
2          cap
3          hat


tbl_ProductCode

Productid  Productcode
1           Clothes
```

I have written the below query to find products that belong to two different classes

```
select productcode, count(1) from tbl_product p
join tbl_productcode pc on p.productid = pc.productid
group by productcode
having count(1)>1
```

It gives the below output

```
Clothes 2
```

However, it is taking the sizes into consideration.

This is causing an issue because there are products as below

```
tbl_Product 
Product ProductId classid
Yellow - S    1    2
Yellow - M    1    2
Yellow - L    1    2
```

This will give output

Clothes 3

Which is giving the size count. But I am only looking for products of different classes, irrespective of the number of sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
COUNT(1)
```

use

```
COUNT(DISTINCT ClassId)
```

That will ignore the different sizes, and just give you the count of how many unique "ClassId" values appear for each ProductId.

Comment: Sorry I don't think that fixes the issue 


    select count(distinct productid)from tbl_product p
    join tbl_productcode pc on p.productid = pc.productid
    
This will give output 1. It won't show that product Green-A, Green-B have different class

Comment: By the way, you change both instances of COUNT(1) to COUNT(DISTINCT ClassId).  Obviously, fixing them up could potentially be quite a time-consuming task .... so hopefully there aren't actually that many results from the query!

Comment: Thanks that helped get the right count for the products